# How to seed data without specifying relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have entity as below:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SomeEntityId { get; set; }
    public SomeEntity SomeEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and the SomeEntity:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityA> EntitiesA { get; set; }
}
```

I want to seed EntityA without any relations:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityA> builder)
{
    builder.HasData(new EntityA
    {
        Id = 1,
        Enabled = true,
        Name = "...",
        Description = "..."
    });
}
```

But I always get error while `update-database` that:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EntitiesA_SomeEntities_SomeEntityId". The conflict occurred in database "DatabaseName", table "dbo.SomeEntities", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

I know that it occurs because EF want's my `SomeEntity` to be not null, but I can't do it nullable because this seeded data is really unique (it's only data that will haven't foreign key).

How can I get around this?

Comment: `EntityA.SomeEntityId` is a duplicate of the associated `SomeEntity.Id`, yes? It should not be there. The `SomeEntity` object contains its key. Sure, the DB fetches the associated collection via a foreign key because the DB is normalized. C# classes are unnormalized, so to speak, by design and intent; a class design is not and should not be (a mirror of) the DB tables. OO classes and databases serve different purposes. Classes have reference variables to associated objects not foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should make your foreign key property nullable i.e. instead of `public int SomeEntityId` to `public int? SomeEnttiyId`

```
public class EntityA
{
   public int Id { get; init; }
   public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int? SomeEntityId { get; set; }
   public SomeEntity SomeEntity { get; set; }
}
```

This way an EntityA record with null value for the foreign key SomeEntityId can be inserted in the database.

Comment: I wanted to omit this because only one record will have null foreign key, but seems that it's only solution. Thanks.

Comment: [See my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74931351/how-to-seed-data-without-specifying-relations#comment132727695_74931351)

Comment: If there is no `SomeEntity` associated, or we choose to not fetch it from the DB then the reference (`SomeEntity`) should be null. This answer however allows a null `Some EntityId` but a non-null `SomeEntity`; and vice versa.  One ends up writing the DB integrity rules into the classes. I cannot overstate how bad that is. Down-vote.